# Error: package org.junit does not exist despite CLASSPATH being set to the right location

Tags: java, junit

I keep running into this error when using javac to try to compile a test file (using windows 10 and git bash) and it's driving me insane.
I have these lines in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
CS61B_FOLDER="${HOME}/cs61b"
export PATH="${CS61B_FOLDER}/cs61b-software/bin:${PATH}"
export CLASSPATH=".:${CS61B_FOLDER}/cs61b-software/lib/*"
```

This is the address that contains JUnit:

```
C:\Users\Vinay\cs61b\cs61b-software\lib
```

This is what I have under the system environment variable for CLASSPATH:

```
%USERPROFILE%\cs61b-software\lib\*;.
```

Does anyone know why it's not recognizing JUnit?

Comment: Do you specify the class path on the command line when calling `javac`? `javac -cp %CLASSPATH% ...`